# Error in selecting and copying data from one datatable into another?

Tags: c#, datatable, .net-3.5

I tried to select some data from one data table and save it to another based on a 
condition. 
I am getting the error - 
System.Data.SyntaxErrorException: Cannot interpret token '!' at position 6.

What is the correct syntax and where can I see a list of C# statements that do queries 
like SQL server.

```
        DataTable parent = some datatable from SQL server;
        DataTable child = new DataTable();
        child = parent.Select("cols != -1").CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: try `"cols <> -1"`     != is a C# operator, see http://www.csharp-examples.net/dataview-rowfilter/ for details of datatable row filter syntax

Comment: @StephenByrne - Thanks. That worked. I wonder why this error occurs. ! is insided a string.

Comment: It's because the filter syntax for filtering DataViewRows in a DataTable is not C# syntax - as Tim detailed below!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you select a table from sql-server which you first need to filter at all? Can't you add this to the `WHERE`-clause?

With .NET 3.5 you should be able to use `Linq-To-DataSet` which is much more powerful and readable:

```
DataTable parent = GetTable();
DataTable child = parent.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(row => row.Field<int>("cols") != -1)
    .CopyToDataTable();
```

If you want to use `DataTable.Select` anyway you have to use `<>` instead of `!=`.

```
DataRow[] filtered = parent.Select("cols <> -1");
```

Have a look here for the expression syntax: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression(v=vs.110).aspx

When you create comparison expressions, the following operators are allowed:

```
<
>
<=
>=
<>
=
IN
LIKE
```

The following arithmetic operators are also supported in expressions:

```
+ (addition)
- (subtraction)
* (multiplication)
/ (division)
% (modulus)
```